# Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ $\iff$ for all sequences sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = f(a)$

I have no idea how to start this. Should I use some sort of $\epsilon/N$ proof? 
Please help ASAP! Thanks in advance

Comment: Which direction are you having trouble with?

Comment: @ColdNumber ? What do you mean?

Comment: You know that you have to prove two directions for an "if and only if" condition right?

Comment: @ZeroXLR no.. i didn't know

Comment: @TanMath one direction is "if $f$ is continuous, then the statement on sequences hold".  The other statement is "if the statement on sequences hold, then $f$ is continuous".  Does it make sense that these two statements are distinct?  Does it make sense to you that we need to prove both?

Comment: Why is everybody downvoting my question? What is the reason? I am trying to get an answer to this question. I hope to make this question better...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, that is clearer...

Comment: @TanMath I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, to be honest. At any rate, have you seen Vadim's answer below?  If it's enough to get you to the answer you're looking for, you should accept it.  Otherwise, I'd suggest you post a comment on his answer about where exactly you can't follow his solution.  Or, you could also post a separate question about the *specific* part(s) of the proof that you're having trouble with.  It seems to  me that you're having trouble grasping the basic definitions.

Comment: What is your definition of limit? Your sentence is just Heine definition, and I don't know what you want to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction: Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous.  Then you need to show $|f(a_n)-f(a)|<\epsilon$, which you can do by making $|a_n-a|$ small enough and using the continuity property.  This direction is easier, a direct proof.

Other direction: Suppose the second property holds, but $f(x)$ is NOT continuous. This direction is harder, a proof by contradiction.  There must be some small $\epsilon$ so that for any $\delta>0$ we can find $a'$ with $|f(a')-f(a)|>\epsilon$ and yet $|a'-a|<\delta$.  Now vary $\delta$ to get a succession of $a'$, ever closer to $a$, but all breaking the epsilon condition.  Make this your sequence $\{a_n\}$, which will contradict the second property.